# How can we integrate google analytics and google tag manager to site developed in strapi and node js?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, strapi

I am new to the Strapi cms, I didn't know how to integrate google analytics and google tag manager to this site.

Comment: Strapi is headless. It's not related to analytics in any way.

Comment: I need to integrate google analytics and tag manager for social media marketing.

Comment: I see. As I said, Strapi is irrelevant. This needs to be done on a website that is hooked to CMS. CMS only provides data for a website.

Comment: And how can I access the site hooked with strapi.@EstusFlask

Comment: This is specific to the project, ask a person who owns it. This isn't a question for SO.